# Open Erp Reporting Through Interface

Tags: reporting, odoo

i have created my module that is asset allocation through interface of which now i want to create report in OPEN ERP v 7 so how i can create reporting through interface

any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You use **xlwt,xlrd** for Excel formatted reporting, but downside is you have to export it external Excel editor.
**xlwt** for main Excel sheet creating and **xlrd** for Excel formula.

```
    import xlrd
    import xlwt
    ezxf = xlwt.easyxf
    styles = self.get_easyxf_styles()

    book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf8')
    sheet = book.add_sheet(u'Properties')
    sheet.portrait = False
    sheet.write(0, 9, u'Item #', ezxf('font:bold on;align:wrap off,vert centre,horiz right;font: height 180'))
    sheet.write(0, 0, u'Organization name: %s' % (company.name,), ezxf('font:bold on;align:wrap off,vert centre,horiz left;font: height 180'))
    sheet.write(rowx, 0, u'Numbering', styles['heading_xf'])
```

Here is usage of **xlrd** for Excel formula:

> sheet.write(rowx, i, xlwt.Formula('SUM(%s:%s)' %(xlrd.cellname(rowx, 2), 
>                                                                   xlrd.cellname(rowx, 8))), styles['number_boldtotal_xf'])

Here is partial snipper of formatting function, you can create your own:

> def get_easyxf_styles(self):
>           styledict = {
>               'title_xf': easyxf('font: bold on, height 250; align: wrap off, vert centre, horiz left;'),
>               'small_title_xf': easyxf('font: bold on, height 190; align: wrap off, vert centre, horiz left;'),
>           }
>           return styledict